# What is the best way to define a set of constants in a web project?

Tags: java

I'm working on an ejb project and I need to define a set of constants that I can use in the whole of my project so I create an interface that hold the set of my constants my question is there a better way in to define constants in web project ?

this an exemple of my constant interface :

```
public interface ejbConstant {
    final String  CONST23= "AB23";
    final String  CONST24= "AB24";
    // ..........
}
```

Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: You could use an `enum`, properties, etc. etc. depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

[Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) has quite good [explanation of this with examples](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1214?layout=false)

According to Joshua Bloch, author of "Effective Java":

> The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces.
>
> That a class uses some constants internally is an implementation
>   detail. Implementing a constant interface causes this implementation
>   detail to leak into the class's exported API. It is of no consequence
>   to the users of a class that the class implements a constant
>   interface. In fact, it may even confuse them. Worse, it represents a
>   commitment: if in a future release the class is modified so that it no
>   longer needs to use the constants, it still must implement the
>   interface to ensure binary compatibility. If a nonfinal class
>   implements a constant interface, all of its subclasses will have their
>   namespaces polluted by the constants in the interface.